# How to get decltype of class in class declaration

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a way to obtain the class type without typing the class name (example on a macro expansion)?

I was hope that `decltype(*this)` was available from class declaration but is not the case.

```
// For example, I want declare a swap from macro expansion without passing class name on macro argument
#define SWAP_METHOD()
    void swap( decltype(*this)& a1, decltype(*this)& a2 )

class A
{
    SWAP_METHOD();
}
```

Comment: What error are you receiving? The macro is expanded in translation phase 4, well before compilation takes place [C++ Standard - 5.2 Phases of translation (lex.phase)](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.phases#1.4)

Comment: So your error is `"error: invalid use of ‘this’ at top level"`?

Comment: *"but [`decltype(*this)` was available from class declaration] is not the case."* -- This is an imprecise conclusion; see [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this). The `this` pointer is available in declarations of non-static member functions, but only after the optional cv-qualifier sequence, which happens to come *after* the parameter list. (No practical difference in your case, though.) A more precise statement would be "I was hoping that `decltype(*this)` was available *in member function parameter list declarations*, but this is not the case."

Comment: If you want to templatize the swap-mthod, why would you define it within the class itself?

Answer (score 3):

The solution with the template metaprogramming. I think this is the simplest solution.

```
#include <utility>

#define SWAP_METHOD()     \
  template <typename T>   \
  void swap(T& a1, T& a2)

class A {
 public:
  SWAP_METHOD();
};

template <>
void A::swap(A& a1, A& a2) {
  std::swap(a1, a2);
}

int main() {
  A a, b, c;
  a.swap(b, c);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yep, that will do it with `<algorithm>` or `<utility>` or `<string_view>` (which I haven' t made much use of yet...`:)`

Comment: but there is a lot of declared functions not implemented...

Comment: @IsaacPascual What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot know self type for parameter.

There are several alternatives, including:

- Require specific typedef:

  ```
  #define SWAP_METHOD() void swap( Self& a1, Self& a2 )

  class A {
  public:
      using Self = A; // Require
      SWAP_METHOD();
  };
  ```
- use CRTP instead of MACRO

```
template <typename Derived>
struct Swappable
{
    static void swap(Derived& d1, Derived& d2) { /*..*/}
};

struct A : Swappable<A> {};
```